# Google ai-platform model definition for earthengine usage

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to host a DNN-model on the Google AI-platform and use this model in the Google Earth for prediction.

However, I can not seem to configure the input-output definition properly. There is an example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-community/blob/master/guides/linked/TF_demo1_keras.ipynb), but without any further explanation.

```py
from tensorflow.python.tools import saved_model_utils

meta_graph_def = saved_model_utils.get_meta_graph_def(config.MODEL_DIR, 'serve')
inputs = meta_graph_def.signature_def['serving_default'].inputs
outputs = meta_graph_def.signature_def['serving_default'].outputs

# Just get the first thing(s) from the serving signature def.  i.e. this
# model only has a single input and a single output.
input_name = None
for k,v in inputs.items():
  input_name = v.name
  break

output_name = None
for k,v in outputs.items():
  output_name = v.name
  break

# Make a dictionary that maps Earth Engine outputs and inputs to 
# AI Platform inputs and outputs, respectively.
import json
input_dict = "'" + json.dumps({input_name: "array"}) + "'"
output_dict = "'" + json.dumps({output_name: "impervious"}) + "'"

# You need to set the project before using the model prepare command.
!earthengine set_project {PROJECT}
!earthengine model prepare --source_dir {config.MODEL_DIR} --dest_dir {config.EEIFIED_DIR} --input {input_dict} --output {output_dict}
```

Is there any mapping/explanation available how the `input_dict` relates to the access in the Earth Engine?

```
var model = ee.Model.fromAiPlatformPredictor({
    projectName: PROJECT,
    modelName: MODEL_NAME,
    version: VERSION_NAME,
    inputTileSize: [pixel_size, pixel_size],
    proj: ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(SCALE),
    fixInputProj: true,
    outputBands: {'land_classes': {
        type: ee.PixelType.float(),
        dimensions: 1
      }
    }
});
```

I fail to understand the mapping and can therefore not use a model of my own.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the "'land_classes':" in outputBands, cause the "output_name" as impervious